# Unexpected duration for v3io content delete

Tags: command-line, hdfs, mlrun

When I deleted content of NoSqlTarget (key-value storage) in MLRun/v3io via standard command line utility such as:

```
rm -rf /v3io/project/test-featureset/
```

It took approx. 1 hour for 1 million of files and in case of 20 millions of files it was near to one day.

Do you have tips/tricks, how to use faster delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got very useful tip for speedup delete process, use this command line:

```
hdfs dfs -rm -f -r v3io://projects/test-featureset/
```

The new performance was excellent, 1 million of files per 3 minutes.

BTW: the command `hdfs dfs` is possible to use for speedup other operations such as `-ls -cp -find`, more information see the [link](https://sparkbyexamples.com/apache-hadoop/hadoop-hdfs-dfs-commands-and-starting-hdfs-dfs-services/)